# Reading request headers from type-graphql resolvers with ApolloServer

Tags: apollo-server, typegraphql

I am following [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-typegraphql/src) example that uses Prisma ORM, ApolloServer and type-graphql to make a simple blog web app.

I want to inspect the HTTP request headers and I'm having trouble working out how to access the ApolloServer `context.headers` in a type-graphql resolver such as [this](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/38da9ba218398642b16acf4fc3dafe2d31c3735d/typescript/graphql-typegraphql/src/PostResolver.ts#L50):

```
  @Query((returns) => Post, { nullable: true })
  async postById(@Arg('id') id: number, @Ctx() ctx: Context) {
    return ctx.prisma.post.findUnique({
      where: { id },
    })
  }
```

The ApolloServer is set up [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/38da9ba218398642b16acf4fc3dafe2d31c3735d/typescript/graphql-typegraphql/src/index.ts#L20) like this:

```
new ApolloServer({ schema, context: context }).listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
    console.log(`Server ready at: http://localhost:4000`), )
```

But the *@Ctx() ctx: Context* referenced in the resolver above is only the Prisma context (defined [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/graphql-typegraphql/src/context.ts)) not the ApolloServer context. If I log the keys for the ctx object I get: `[ 'prisma', '_extensionStack' ]`

In past ApolloServer projects that do not use type-graphql decorators I have accessed the ApolloServer context like this:

```
postById: async (_, { id }, apolloServerContext) => {... console.log(apolloServerContext.headers)
```

How can I access the request headers from the resolver that uses type-graphql decorators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IncomingMessage` as the type of the context object in the Resolver query.

But first, you need to pass `context` parameter to ApolloServer's constructor like the following:

```
new ApolloServer({
  schema: schema,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    return req;
  },
 });
```

Then you will be able to consume it in the Resolver like this:

```
import { Ctx, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";
import { IncomingMessage } from "http";

@Resolver()
export class TestResolver {
  constructor(private readonly service: TestService) {}

  @Query(() => Data, { nullable: true })
  async getDataForUser(@Ctx() context: IncomingMessage): Promise<Data> {
    const headers = context.headers;
    return await this.service.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the authorization API from Type-GQL to get the headers into the context and write business logic to further use them.

You can add as a function or a class level.

*Example for function*

```
export const customAuthChecker: AuthChecker<ContextType> = (
  { root, args, context, info },
  roles,
) => {
  // here we can read the user from context
  // and check his permission in the db against the `roles` argument
  // that comes from the `@Authorized` decorator, eg. ["ADMIN", "MODERATOR"]

  return true; // or false if access is denied
};
```

In the above ContextType is the object that you can create and use like a POJO etc.